# Why is this sort necessary in quick sort application

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I am trying to understand the code in an application of quicksort to find the kth smallest element.

Here is the code that the author wrote

```
public class KthSmallest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] test = {2,3,1,5,7,6,9};
        System.out.println("4th smallest is " + quick_select(test, 4, 0, test.length - 1));
    }
    private static int quick_select(int[] a, int k, int left, int right) {
         int pivot=findpivot(a,left,right);
         if(pivot==k-1){
              return a[pivot];
         }
         if(k-1<pivot){
              return quick_select(a, k, left, pivot-1);
          }
          else {
              return quick_select(a, k, pivot+1, right);
          }
        }
        private static int findpivot(int[] a, int left, int right) {
            int pivot = a[(left+right)/2];
            while(left<right){
                while(a[left]<pivot){
                    left++;
                }
                while(a[right]>pivot){
                    right--;
                }

                if(left<=right){
                    swap(a,left,right);
                    left++;
                    right--;
                }

            }
            return left;
        }

        private static void swap(int[] a, int i, int j) {
            int temp=a[i];
            a[i]=a[j];
            a[j]=temp;

        }


}
```

I am trying to understand what the significance of this code segment in find pivot

```
     if(left<=right){
                    swap(a,left,right);
                    left++;
                    right--;
        }
```

Here is what you know. All the elements to the left of left are smaller than pivot. All the elements to the right of right of right are greater than pivot. Can anyone explain with that intuition why it is necessary to swap if right>= left?

Comment: It's not really a duplicate because that code in the other one didn't even work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can anyone explain with that intuition why it is necessary to swap if
>   right>= left?

`right` and `left` are indexes - not the items themselves (which is probably the source of your confusion). If a number to the "right" of the pivot is smaller than the pivot it should be moved to the left of the pivot.

Respectively, if a number to the left of the pivot is bigger than the pivot - it should be moved to the right (of the pivot).

Once we run into two such items, we use the `if` condition to make sure that we didn't go "too far" in the previous loops and that the numbers that were found really should be swapped, this check - tests that the indexes `left <= right` otherwise there's no reason to do the swap (or continue running...).

**Note**: The explanation in the last paragraph show that we don't really have to check `if(left<=right)` - it's good enough to check that `if(left<right)`

Comment: if (left == right), wouldn't it be necessary to run the left ++ and right ++ code?

Comment: `if (left == right)` you don't need to swap because it's the same item...

Comment: if right > left, this means that they haven't crossed. All elements to right of right are greater than pivot. All elements to left of left are less than pivot. From that, can you explain why the swap is necessary?

Comment: "All elements to right of right are greater than pivot. All elements to left of left are less than pivot. " exactly! But this condition is about the items *on* the right index (and not about the items "to the right of the right index" and same goes for the left respectively(.

Answer (score 1):

The first loop moves `left` to the right until it finds an element that is greater than the pivot. The second loop moves `right` to the left until it finds an element less than the pivot. At this point `a[left]` should move after the pivot and `a[right]` should move before the pivot, the if takes care of that.

Comment: What if hypothetically, left > right?

Comment: If left > right it means that we went too far in the previous `while` iterations and that we are actually done sorting (so the `if` won't get executed and  we'll get out of the outer wihle-loop since the condition `left<right` is no longer true

Comment: I can't go from left > right to us being done with sorting and right > left to not being done with sorting......